# Dynamic Object array and multiple values

Tags: javascript

description of problem :

i have two values given belows and i get **id** and their **time** by click on button

each id has their multiple times in array object

i tried but its problem

```
pushToAry("id4","10.12");

function pushToAry(id, val) {
   var obj = {};

   if(id&& val){

    obj = {id:song_name};

    arrbookmark.push(obj);

    var temp = {};

    for(var i in arrbookmark){

        if(song_name == arrbookmark[i].id){

          arrbookmark[i].i_current_times = {cur_time :val};

        }

    }

    console.log(arrbookmark)

   }

}
```

Output like same as below

**Output Like**

```
var usersHours = [{

 id1: {

    0 :10,

    1 : 11,

    2 :12

},

id2: {

    0 :1,

    1 :11,

    2 :9

},

id3: {

    0 :8,

    1 :9,

    2 :7

 }

}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to add bookmarks on the time line of a song:

```
function addBookmark(id, timeString) {
   var found = false;
   for (var i in BOOKMARK) {
       if (id == BOOKMARK[i].songId) {
            BOOKMARK[i].bookmarks.push(timeString);
            found = true;
            break;
       }
   }
   if (!found) {
       var obj = {songId: id, bookmarks: [timeString]};
       BOOKMARK.push(obj);
   }
   console.log(BOOKMARK);
}
```

Comment: nearest answer but if ID is already exists then and again get new time also push on existing ID bcoz multiple times on each ID if its possible..

Comment: Yes, I know it's not a complete solution, partially because you never told us what the output should look like.

Comment: Anyway I unerstand what you mean now probably, let me edit my answer.

Comment: i changed output same as above just look at above  by the way thank you very much

Comment: Now its perfact output thank you very much first time some help me on stackoverflow

Comment: You're welcome, and you were right. I accepted, note I also forgot the var before obj.